# Boto DynamoDb - JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request - really weird behaviour

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I'm working with the Boto DynamoDb2 API and I'm experiencing something really strange. First off, I'm using an IAM Role for authentication and the code I'm about to show is being run on an EC2 instance with the attached Role. The Role has full administrative permissions and I'm positive the issue isn't related to permissions.

I have code that creates a table and then adds an item to that table. However, the first time I `put_item`, it throws an exception, but it works the next time right afterwards. Here's a dump from my python interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 11 2015, 23:39:10) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto.dynamodb2
>>> from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
>>> from boto.dynamodb2.fields import HashKey
>>> from boto.dynamodb2.types import NUMBER
>>> 
>>> table = Table.create('myTablse',
...     schema=[HashKey('index', data_type=NUMBER)],
...     connection=boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1'))
>>> 
>>> table.put_item(data={
...     'index': 4,
...     'sequence': 'sdfsdf34rfdsa'
... })
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/fyp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/table.py", line 821, in put_item
    return item.save(overwrite=overwrite)
  File "/home/ec2-user/fyp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/items.py", line 455, in save
    returned = self.table._put_item(final_data, expects=expects)
  File "/home/ec2-user/fyp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/table.py", line 835, in _put_item
    self.connection.put_item(self.table_name, item_data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/fyp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 1510, in put_item
    body=json.dumps(params))
  File "/home/ec2-user/fyp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2842, in make_request
    retry_handler=self._retry_handler)
  File "/home/ec2-user/fyp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 954, in _mexe
    status = retry_handler(response, i, next_sleep)
  File "/home/ec2-user/fyp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2885, in _retry_handler
    data)
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'Requested resource not found', u'__type': u'com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ResourceNotFoundException'}
>>> table.put_item(data={
...     'index': 4,
...     'sequence': 'sdfsdf34rfdsa'
... })
True
>>>
```

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. When you submit the CreateTable API call and it returns a 200, that doesn't mean that the table is created yet or ready to use for that matter as everything seems to happen asynchronously.

So basically, you need to wait until the table is ready before you can add items to it. Here is my solution:

```
 con = boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1')

table = Table.create('myTables',
    schema=[HashKey('index', data_type=NUMBER)],
    connection=con)

while True:
    try:
        r=con.describe_table('myTables')
        if r and r['Table']['TableStatus'] == 'ACTIVE':
            break
    except JSONResponseError, e:
        if 'resource not found' in e.message:
            pass
        else:
            raise
    time.sleep(1)

table.put_item(data={
    'index': 4,
    'sequence': 'sdfsdf34rfdsa'
})
```

Hope this helps someone else!